# Cannot find file setuptools-27.2.0-py3.5.egg

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, setuptools

This question is for Python 3.5.2, using Anaconda 4.3.0 on Windows 10 (64-bit)

When I try to install packages with pip I get this error:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\HMGSYS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-xit1wtvr\shapely\
```

Based on other SO answers, I tried to  upgrade setuptools:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

But I get this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\HMGSYS\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.5.egg'
```

However, if I try to install setuptools:

```
python -m pip install -U pip setuptools
```

It tells me that all packages are up to date, including setuptools:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in c:\users\hmgsys\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
```

Also, when I look in lib\site-packages, I see a folder for setuptools and another for setuptools-34.3.2.dist-info.

What should I try next? Why is setuptools looking for version 27.2.0 and ignoring the more recent versions?

EDIT:

I downloaded the specific version of setuptools that the system was looking for and the error from 'pip install --upgrade setuptools' disappeared. However, I'm still getting the first 'egg_info' error. I've also installed ez_setup, which had no effect.

Comment: None of the proposed answers worked for me so I ended up wiping Windows and reinstalling Windows 7 (for this and other reasons). I don't recommend this, but it did fix the problem.

Comment: Having the .egg not found problem, but reinstalling windows is not an option for me.

Comment: Same here. My Python 2.7 env is also affected.

Answer (score 21):

Try to use conda to update setuptools:

conda update setuptools

Comment: I tried that and conda updated but I still get the error.

Answer (score 4):

You may try to downgrade your python into python 3.5.0.

```
conda install python=3.5.0
```

( I had encountered the same error with python 3.5.3, and it installed without error after downgraded to 3.5.0.)